# Access vba parse xml file

Tags: xml, vba, parsing, msxml

I have to parse a xml file like this one

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:camt.054.001.04 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:camt.054.001.04 camt.054.001.04.xsd">
<BkToCstmrDbtCdtNtfctn>
<Ntfctn>
    <Ntry>
        <NtryDtls>
            <Btch><NbOfTxs>11</NbOfTxs></Btch>
            <TxDtls>
                <Refs><AcctSvcrRef>170920CH026MFE07</AcctSvcrRef><Prtry><Ref>170920CH026MFE07</Ref></Prtry></Refs>
                <Amt Ccy="CHF">50.00</Amt>
                <CdtDbtInd>CRDT</CdtDbtInd>
                <BkTxCd><Domn><Cd>PMNT</Cd><Fmly><Cd>RCDT</Cd><SubFmlyCd>ATXN</SubFmlyCd></Fmly></Domn></BkTxCd>
                <RltdPties><Dbtr><Nm>Dupond Jacques</Nm><PstlAdr><AdrLine>Avenue de la Gare 16</AdrLine><AdrLine>1950 Sion</AdrLine></PstlAdr></Dbtr><DbtrAcct><Id><IBAN>CH0210565000H01320398</IBAN></Id></DbtrAcct></RltdPties>
                <RltdAgts>
                    <DbtrAgt><FinInstnId><ClrSysMmbId><MmbId>765</MmbId></ClrSysMmbId><Nm>Banque Cantonale du Valais</Nm><PstlAdr><AdrLine>Place des Cèdres 8</AdrLine><AdrLine>1951 Sion/Sitten</AdrLine></PstlAdr></FinInstnId></DbtrAgt>
                </RltdAgts>
                <RmtInf><Strd><CdtrRefInf><Tp><CdOrPrtry><Prtry>ISR Reference</Prtry></CdOrPrtry></Tp><Ref>010000000039630008930301504</Ref></CdtrRefInf><AddtlRmtInf>?REJECT?0</AddtlRmtInf></Strd></RmtInf>
                <RltdDts><AccptncDtTm>2017-09-20T20:00:00</AccptncDtTm></RltdDts>
            </TxDtls>
            <TxDtls>
                <Refs><AcctSvcrRef>170920CH026O37E1</AcctSvcrRef><EndToEndId>NOTPROVIDED</EndToEndId><Prtry><Tp>01</Tp><Ref>170920CH026O37E1</Ref></Prtry></Refs>
                <Amt Ccy="CHF">30.00</Amt>
                <CdtDbtInd>CRDT</CdtDbtInd>
                <BkTxCd><Domn><Cd>PMNT</Cd><Fmly><Cd>RCDT</Cd><SubFmlyCd>ATXN</SubFmlyCd></Fmly></Domn></BkTxCd>
                <RltdPties>
                    <Dbtr><Nm>Monsieur Gilbert Dayer und</Nm><PstlAdr><AdrLine>Madame Laurence Darabie</AdrLine><AdrLine>1967 Bramois</AdrLine></PstlAdr></Dbtr>
                    <DbtrAcct><Id><IBAN>CH0700556031023502008</IBAN></Id></DbtrAcct>
                </RltdPties>
                <RltdAgts>
                    <DbtrAgt>
                        <FinInstnId>
                            <ClrSysMmbId><MmbId>765</MmbId></ClrSysMmbId>
                            <Nm>Banque Cantonale du Valais</Nm>
                            <PstlAdr><AdrLine>Place des Cèdres 8</AdrLine><AdrLine>1951 Sion/Sitten</AdrLine></PstlAdr>
                        </FinInstnId>
                    </DbtrAgt>
                </RltdAgts>
                <RmtInf><Strd><CdtrRefInf><Tp><CdOrPrtry><Prtry>ISR Reference</Prtry></CdOrPrtry></Tp><Ref>010000000018630005104202604</Ref></CdtrRefInf><AddtlRmtInf>?REJECT?0</AddtlRmtInf></Strd></RmtInf>
                <RltdDts><AccptncDtTm>2017-09-20T20:00:00</AccptncDtTm></RltdDts>
            </TxDtls>

        </NtryDtls>
    </Ntry>
</Ntfctn>
```

I have to get the information between the node *TxDtls*. I want to get each by each. Is that possible?

I have tried this one

```vb
Public Sub getNom()

    Dim oXML As MSXML2.DOMDocument
    Dim oNode As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
    Dim oNodeList As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList
    Dim oSubNode As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
    Dim name, value As String

    Set oXML = New MSXML2.DOMDocument   
    oXML.async = False
    oXML.Load (txtNomFichier) '"C:\XMLFileXMLIndent.xml"

    ' 1 niveau plus bas
    For Each oNode In oXML.SelectNodes("//TxDtls")
       Debug.Print oNode.Text
    Next

End Sub
```

With this it become all lines betetwen each node *TxDtls*. But how can I get each child node of *TxDtls*? Thanks for your help.

Comment: What have you tried so far? We prefer you to have a go at solving your own problem before asking for help and explain what you have tried. Perhaps search for _parsing xml in vba_ first and see what that returns

Comment: Hello, i change my problem ? I tried a lot of solution but i dont know how to get it. thanks for you help

Comment: oNode should have a childNodes property: oNode.childNodes

Comment: Your code should have not returned anything as you have default namespace with no assigned prefix.